# MONGOOSE - Display only the specific value I've inputted inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good day, I've spent 2 - 3 hours just to get this working,

so I have this controller.js code:

```
const b_name = req.params.b;
const m_name = req.params.m;
const result = await cinemaDB.getcinemasbranchesmovies(model, {'details.branches_name': b_name, 'details.movies_name': m_name});
```

and this db.js code:

```
/** Get  branches's movies by _id */
module.exports.getcinemasbranchesmovies =
async(model, query) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // console.log("branches: " + b_name + "movies: "+ m_name);
    if (!query) {
      query = {};
    }

    console.log("branches: ", query);
    model.find(query)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("branches: ", res);
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(err);
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });

});
}
```

and this route.js code:

```
server.get("/api/cinemas/getcbm/:b/:m",controller.getcinemasbranchesmovies);
```

EDIT! If you put it in a query:

`model.find({'details.branches_name': "Evia", 'details.movies_name': "Greatest"})`

now this is the JSON result:

```
{
"success": true,
"status": "OK",
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "5ab49348c356c713a836cc15",
        "cinemas_name": "Cinemas 3",
        "__v": 0,
        "details": [
            {
                "price": 350,
                "movies_name": "Black Panther",
                "branches_name": "Bataan",
                "_id": "5ab49348c356c713a836cc16",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "branches_name": "Bataan",
                "movies_name": "Black Panther",
                "price": 350,
                "_id": "5ab494b2c0a83c28e874ace9",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "branches_name": "Bataan",
                "movies_name": "Black Panther",
                "price": 350,
                "_id": "5ab495a9d0bebb3d4c26c086",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "branches_name": "Bataan",
                "movies_name": "December Avenue",
                "price": 350,
                "_id": "5ab495c5d0bebb3d4c26c087",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "branches_name": "Taguig",
                "movies_name": "December Avenue",
                "price": 350,
                "_id": "5ab49d4b2b0ce727dc9a2a07",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "branches_name": "Evia",
                "movies_name": "December Avenue",
                "price": 350,
                "_id": "5ab49d522b0ce727dc9a2a08",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "branches_name": "Evia",
                "movies_name": "Greatest",
                "price": 350,
                "_id": "5ab4a0e397ca122e8005c19f",
                "time": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Now what I need only is this value to be displayed:

```
{
"success": true,
"status": "OK",
"data": [
            {
                "_id": "5ab49348c356c713a836cc15",
                "cinemas_name": "Cinemas 3",
                "__v": 0,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "branches_name": "Evia",
                        "movies_name": "Greatest",
                        "price": 350,
                        "_id": "5ab4a0e397ca122e8005c19f",
                        "time": [
                            "1",
                            "2",
                            "3"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

So all in all, I want only to display the specific data I've inputted inside the query of find. 
I do search it on google first, but I can't comprehend the way they code it.

Comment: Please mention that query specifically.

Comment: `model.find({'details.branches_name': "Evia", 'details.movies_name': "Greatest"})`

Comment: Whats the difference between two responses ? I couldn't figure out the diff between the two.

Comment: The *now this is the JSON result* is what my current query displays. 
The last one is what I want the query to display, 

I intend to display only object inside an object I've search for.

If I want to search for Bataan & Black Panther all the Black Panther with Bataan values will be displayed and not including the other array of objects which does not include black panther and Bataan.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, expanding my comprehension on google, I get it done by using the aggregate function.

replacing `model.find` -> `model.aggregate`

it's query is something like:

```
model.aggregate({$unwind:"$details"}, 
                {
                    $match:{
                        "details.branches_name": query1, 
                        "details.movies_name": query2
                    } 
                } 
            )
```

I hope someone helps by this :D